# matching in scala map to an object

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

In all the scala examples on the web like this one

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html

there always seems to be a superclass.  Is there a way to avoid needing a superclass or is that necessary.  For instance, can I do something like this..

```
def matchMe(map: Map[String, String]) {
  map match {
    case searchReq @ SearchQueryRequestParams() => System.out.println("something=" + query)
    //case countReq@CountRequestParams() => System.out.println("count req=" + countReq)
    case _ => System.out.println("match nothing")
  }
}
```

This however does not compile complaining that Map[String, String] is required.  I have unapply methods that take that parameter as seen here

```
trait SearchValidatorBase {
  def unapply(params: Map[String, String]): Option[CommonQueryRequestParams] = {
    val query = params.get("query")
    val fromDateStr = params.get("fromDate")
    val toDateStr = params.get("toDate")
    Some(CommonQueryRequestParams(query, fromDateStr, toDateStr))
  }
}

object CountMatching extends SearchValidatorBase {
  override def unapply(params: Map[String, String]): Option[CountRequestParams] = {
    val result = super.unapply(params)
    val commonParams = result.getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("bug, should always have a CommonQueryRequestParams"))
    val bucket = params.get("bucket")
    Some(CountRequestParams(commonParams, bucket))
  }
}

object SearchMatching extends SearchValidatorBase {
  override def unapply(params: Map[String, String]): Option[SearchQueryRequestParams] = {
    val result = super.unapply(params)
    val commonParams = result.getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("bug, should always have a CommonQueryRequestParams"))
    val maxResults = params.get("maxResults")
    val nextToken = params.get("nextToken")
    Some(SearchQueryRequestParams(commonParams, maxResults, nextToken))
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong as the compiler doesn't like my code?

Next, is there a clean way to validate and translate to Boolean, Ints, etc...as currently my objects are all Option[String] as in the following

```
case class CommonQueryRequestParams(
                                         originalQuery: Option[String],
                                         fromDate: Option[String],
                                         toDate: Option[String]
                                         )
case class SearchQueryRequestParams(
                               commonRequest: CommonQueryRequestParams,
                               maxResults: Option[String],
                               nextToken: Option[String])

case class CountRequestParams(commonRequest: CommonQueryRequestParams, bucket: Option[String])
```

Ideally, I want to return clean errors back to the user like fromDate is invalid(I want a DateTime there actually and an Int in maxResults, etc. etc.)

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

ah, I wasn't using the entities with the unapply methods so this fixes it

```
def matchMe(map: Map[String, String]) {
  map match {
    case searchReq @ SearchMatching() => System.out.println("something=" + searchReq)
    //case countReq@CountRequestParams() => System.out.println("count req=" + countReq)
    case _ => System.out.println("match nothing")
  }
}
```